# AVPlayerViewController did exit full screen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to know when an AVPlayerViewController was dismissed or exited full screen in order to change its parent view controller layout but I'm having no luck finding a delegate method that tells me when it happens.

I've tried adding an observer on the view controller like so:

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath))
playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController?.delegate = self
playerController!.player = player

playerController?.contentOverlayView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
addChildViewController(playerController!)
```

but it's never triggered.

I just want to know when `playerController`is being dismissed or user exited full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in the parent view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let playerController = playerController {
        // handle exit of playerController here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want track user exit fullscreen or state of video, you can use MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Yup but this has been deprecated since iOS 9 and I don't like deprecated stuff. :)